# Error code 1060 duplicate column id in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql

I want to make a temporary table like this :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE A  
    SELECT * 
    FROM order_seller os 
    INNER JOIN product p ON os.product_id = p.id
    WHERE os.active = 1 
    ORDER BY os.product_id;
```

but I get this error:

> Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'id'

What is my mistake?

My column is all of row in table order_seller and all row in table product, please assist where my wrong at? I've tried the solution in this question but I don't know what to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like both tables `order_seller` and `product` contain columns named `id`.
Enumerate the columns in the SELECT list and change the names by using aliases so there are no duplicates:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY table  A  
select os.id as os_id, os.col1, os.col2, ..., 
       p.id as p_id, p.othercol1, p.othercol2, .... 
from order_seller os inner join product p on os.product_id = p.id
where os.active = 1 order by os.product_id;
```